# Know any metaphors about women that...?

Tags: poetry, sex

... are very skilled in getting men to like them, men really easily fall in love with them, but they (the women) are not interested in anything more than a sexual relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to make the women look good, or bad?  Like, are they deliberately hurting the men who fall for them, or have they been honest about their intentions and just can't help it if men don't believe them?

If you're looking for a negative metaphor, I think the Greeks could probably help.  Helen of Troy springs to mind, but maybe also Pandora, the Sirens, most of the women in the Odyssey, etc.  The Greeks weren't big fans of independent women.  Or something more modern, although maybe overused - the black widow spider (lures males into her web, mates, kills them).

If you're looking for a more positive perspective...could you pull something out of nature?  Anything that can be pleasant but that ultimately follows its own path should work, right?  Like, the warmth of the sun that lasts only a while before it fades to night, the cold moon that men stare at and dream about but can't control...that sort of thing?

Good luck with it.

Comment: I was looking for a positive representation (should have mentioned that, sorry). Thank you for the detailed post.

Answer (score 3):

From "Gone With the Wind":

> Melanie: That's not fair. The men naturally flock to her. Scarlett's just high spirited and vivacious.
>
> Sue Ellen: Men may flirt with a girl like that but they don't marry them.

Answer (score 0):

What about "Lady vamp" or - better - "succuba" (not "succubus")? "Succubian lady vamp"?

Comment: why succuba and not succubus?

Comment: @Laurem Ipsum: for "succubus" is a daemon, an unnatural being. Woman described in question seems to be a pretty natural one.

Comment: Then what's a succubA? I'm not asking about the adjectival form of succubus.

Comment: Just Latin feminine gender (dominus -> domina, ...) - allegedly, daemons are inherently asexual (no gender) and their motives are inferior ... etc.